# How do I make sure that the domain is up and the CLI is connected to its controller?

Tags: batch-file, jboss, server, wildfly

I'm new to JBoss.How do I make  sure that  the domain is up and the CLI is connected to its controller ?

When I run jboss-cli.bat, and tried to connect its connecting and showing:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /]
```

That is, it is running in standalone mode.

Now my doubt is that , how to change this mode. I want to start server in domain mode. What all changes I have to do so that I will get:

```
[domain@localhost:9999 /]
```

Someone please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have started JBoss in standalone mode. There are two scripts to start JBoss, `standalone.bat` and `domain.bat`. If you start JBoss using `domain.bat` then it will start in domain mode.

I actually wrote a blog about domain mode just the other day, which you might find useful as background reading:

http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2015/02/jboss-eap-6-domain-mode.html